# Display images using Base64 and Node.js

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, base64, image

I'm trying to get some blob files (images) and then display it on the screen using base64.

This is my node.js code:

```
var queryimage = "SELECT iproduct FROM images";
connection.query(queryimage, function(err, rows, fields){
    socket.emit('image_prova', new Buffer(rows, 'binary').toString('base64'));
});
```

Then I'm getting the suposed string:

```
websocket.on('image_prova', function(data){
    $('#imagehere').append('<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data+' />');
});
```

The image is not being displayed and the string given is: AA==

I don't understand why...!

Comment: `AA==` is base64 for `\0`(null)

Comment: Wow.. Is this node.js? Funky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `rows` instead of `rows[0]` to `Buffer`. You only requested one, but it is still an array, so you need to access the one you actually want.

If that doesn't work, let me know.